# Undefined columns selected error in R

Tags: r

I apologize in advance because I'm extremely new to coding and was thrust into it just a few days ago by my boss for a project.

My data set is called s1. S1 has 123 variables and 4 of them have some form of "QISSUE" in their name. I want to take these four variables and duplicate them all, adding "Rec" to the end of each one (That way I can freely play with the new variables, while still maintaining the actual ones).

Running this line of code keeps giving me an error:

```
b<- llply(s1[,
            str_c(names(s1)
                     [str_detect(names(s1), fixed("QISSUE"))], 
                              "Rec")],table)
```

The error is as such:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(s1, , str_c(names(s1)[str_detect(names(s1), fixed("QISSUE")) &  : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just break it up into little steps and troubleshoot those?

Comment: If you want to freely play with variables without affecting the original, you can just make a copy `playdf <- s1`

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the subset. Of course there is other ways to do that with simpler code

```
b<- llply(s1[,
             names(s1)[str_detect(names(s1), fixed("QISSUE"))]
             ],c)

nwnam=str_c(names(s1)[str_detect(names(s1), fixed("QISSUE"))],"Rec")
ndf=data.frame(do.call(cbind,b));colnames(ndf)=nwnam
ndf 
# of course you can do 
cbind(s1,ndf)
```